# Outlook explorer activate handler--DoEvents causes Outlook window to maximize

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that runs when an explorer is activated. I discovered that if I put a DoEvents function/statement in the macro, then any time I use another app (say, a browser) and then click back on the main Outlook (i.e., explorer) window title bar, the Outlook window maximizes, as if I had double-clicked on it.

If I comment DoEvents out, the window behaves normally.

This behavior occurs even when DoEvents is the **only** statement in the Activate macro.

The macro runs as expected when the Activate event occurs, but the window state changes for no apparent reason if DoEvents is present.

Is this a known issue?

Thanks!

==== EDIT =====

If I run the following code in ThisOutlookSession, the strange window behavior occurs:

```
Private WithEvents my_x As Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set my_x = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub 

Private Sub my_x_Activate()
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

In addition, clicking once on an item in an explorer **when Outlook does not have the focus** causes the item to open, as if double-clicked. Plus occasional other strange behaviors.

I am using Outlook 2013 in Win10.

Comment: What code do you have in the [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event ?

Comment: See new info above.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use DoEvents. Ever. You might be stealing some of the Windows messages that Outlook itself expected to handle.

Comment: I suppose it's another question, but I had DoEvents in there because there were times when the Activate event fired, the macro executed, but the Explorer object had not fully updated yet--in the specific instance, the last item in the explorer was deleted via an inspector. When the inspector closed, the explorer was activated, but it still showed a selection count of 1, which raised an error when the code tried to access the "selected" item that wasn't really there. DoEvents solved that problem but created a new one.

Comment: You can trap that exception and ignore it if you know what is causing it.

Comment: That is what I did. I was just curious about the strange window behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest scanning your machine for viruses.

Then I'd recommend checking the list of running add-ins in Outlook. You may try to turn them off and see how Outlook works after.

There is no need to use the `DoEvents` in the `Activate` event handler.

Comment: No viruses found when I scanned it today. I have gotten the message that DoEvents is not necessary, but in fact it prevented the error I was getting (see my comment to Dmitry's answer below). I'd rather prevent an error than trap and bypass it if possible. But thanks for the advice.